# Xamarin android Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 12105 (Threadpool work)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

In my Xamarin android app i have this error.
Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 12105 (Threadpool work)

Here is my latest run in debugging mode.
My app works correctly but in some of my runs, it`s ran into this problem and stops working forcely.

> Android application is debugging.

```
01-23 15:12:08.789 F/art     (12072): art/runtime/runtime.cc:419] 

"Thread-23" prio=5 tid=29 WaitingPerformingGc
01-23 15:12:08.789 F/art     (12072): art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x32c07ee0 self=0xcad5c200
01-23 15:12:08.789 F/art     (12072): art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   | sysTid=12164 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xbb09d920
01-23 15:12:08.789 F/art     (12072): art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=228 stm=26 core=3 HZ=100
01-23 15:12:08.789 F/art     (12072): art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   | stack=0xbaf9f000-0xbafa1000 stackSize=1022KB
01-23 15:12:08.789 F/art     (12072): art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   | held mutexes=
01-23 15:12:08.789 F/art     (12072): art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   kernel: __switch_to+0x80/0x8c
01-23 15:12:08.789 F/art     (12072): art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   kernel: futex_wait+0xe8/0x1d8
01-23 15:12:08.789 F/art     (12072): art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   kernel: do_futex+0xc8/0x860
01-23 15:12:08.789 F/art     (12072): art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   kernel: compat_SyS_futex+0xc8/0x144
01-23 15:12:08.789 F/art     (12072): art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   kernel: __sys_trace+0x48/0x4c
01-23 15:12:08.789 F/art     (12072): art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #11 pc 000c0e8f  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8CheckJNI10NewObjectVEP7_JNIEnvP7_jclassP10_jmethodIDSt9__va_list+530)
01-23 15:12:08.790 F/art     (12072): art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #15 pc 000a5713  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (???)
01-23 15:12:08.790 F/art     (12072): art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #16 pc 003544b9  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (Java_android_graphics_BitmapFactory_nativeDecodeByteArray___3BIILandroid_graphics_BitmapFactory_00024Options_2+140)
01-23 15:12:08.790 F/art     (12072): art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeByteArray(Native method)
01-23 15:12:08.790 F/art     (12072): art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(BitmapFactory.java:613)
01-23 15:12:08.790 F/art     (12072): art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(BitmapFactory.java:636)
01-23 15:12:08.790 F/art     (12072): art/runtime/runtime.cc:419] 
01-23 15:12:08.790 F/art     (12072): art/runtime/runtime.cc:419] "Thread-24" prio=5 tid=30 Native
01-23 15:12:08.790 F/art     (12072): art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x32c07f70 self=0xc7c64a00
01-23 15:12:08.790 F/art     (12072): art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   | sysTid=12165 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xb6eec920
01-23 15:12:08.790 F/art     (12072): art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=312 stm=36 core=3 HZ=100
01-23 15:12:08.790 F/art     (12072): art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   | stack=0xb6dee000-0xb6df0000 stackSize=1022KB
01-23 15:12:08.790 F/art     (12072): art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   | held mutexes=
01-23 15:12:08.790 F/art     (12072): art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   kernel: futex_wait_queue_me+0xe0/0x144
01-23 15:12:08.790 F/art     (12072): art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   kernel: futex_wait+0xe8/0x1d8
01-23 15:12:08.790 F/art     (12072): art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   kernel: do_futex+0xc8/0x860
01-23 15:12:08.790 F/art     (12072): art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   kernel: __sys_trace+0x48/0x4c
01-23 15:12:08.790 F/art     (12072): art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #00 pc 00017534  /system/lib/libc.so (syscall+32)
01-23 15:12:08.790 F/art     (12072): art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #01 pc 00047b1b  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL24__pthread_cond_timedwaitP23pthread_cond_internal_tP15pthread_mutex_tbPK8timespec+102)
01-23 15:12:08.790 F/art     (12072): art/runtime/runtime.cc:419] 
01-23 15:12:08.790 F/art     (12072): art/runtime/runtime.cc:419] "Binder:12072_3" prio=5 tid=31 Native
01-23 15:12:08.790 F/art     (12072): art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x32c0f0d0 self=0xc8055f00
01-23 15:12:08.790 F/art     (12072): art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   | sysTid=12170 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xb6357920
01-23 15:12:08.790 F/art     (12072): art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=2 stm=2 core=0 HZ=100
01-23 15:12:08.790 F/art     (12072): art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   | stack=0xb625b000-0xb625d000 stackSize=1014KB
01-23 15:12:08.790 F/art     (12072): art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   | held mutexes=
01-23 15:12:08.790 F/art     (12072): art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   kernel: compat_SyS_ioctl+0x10c/0x1250
01-23 15:12:08.790 F/art     (12072): art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   kernel: __sys_trace+0x48/0x4c
01-23 15:12:08.790 F/art     (12072): art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #00 pc 00049554  /system/lib/libc.so (__ioctl+8)
01-23 15:12:08.790 F/art     (12072): art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #01 pc 0001b33f  /system/lib/libc.so (ioctl+38)
01-23 15:12:08.790 F/art     (12072): art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #02 pc 0003ce89  /system/lib/libbinder.so (_ZN7android14IPCThreadState14talkWithDriverEb+168)
01-23 15:12:08.790 F/art     (12072): art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #05 pc 0004f935  /system/lib/libbinder.so (???)
01-23 15:12:08.790 F/art     (12072): art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #06 pc 0000e329  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Thread11_threadLoopEPv+144)
01-23 15:12:08.790 F/art     (12072): art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #07 pc 0006a485  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android14AndroidRuntime15javaThreadShellEPv+80)
01-23 15:12:08.790 F/art     (12072): art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #08 pc 00047f93  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+22)
01-23 15:12:08.790 F/art     (12072): art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #09 pc 0001a161  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+6)
01-23 15:12:08.790 F/art     (12072): art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   (no managed stack frames)
01-23 15:12:08.791 F/libc    (12072): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 12105 (Threadpool work)
01-23 15:12:08.798 I/art     (12072): Clamp target GC heap from 528MB to 512MB
01-23 15:12:08.798 I/art     (12072): Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 0(0B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 512MB/512MB, paused 753us total 74.922ms
01-23 15:12:08.798 I/art     (12072): WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 456.940ms for cause Alloc
01-23 15:12:08.798 I/art     (12072): Starting a blocking GC Alloc
01-23 15:12:08.798 I/art     (12072): Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
01-23 15:12:08.798 I/art     (12072): Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
```

on of my main codes i guess thrown this exception is:

```
void SetImage(byte[] kalaImage)
        {
            activity.RunOnUiThread(async delegate
            {
                try
                {
                    if (kalaImage != null && kalaImage.Length != 0)
                    {
                        //Task.WaitAll(Task.Run(async () =>
                        Bitmap bitmap = await BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArrayAsync(kalaImage, 0, kalaImage.Length);
                        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
                        bool bResult = await bitmap.CompressAsync(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 50 / 100, stream);
                        if (bResult)
                        {
                            imageView.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        }
                        //));
                    }
                }
                catch { }
            });
        }
```

Please help me with this!
Thanks

Comment: Looks like you are running out of memory when working with the bitmap

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT Yes! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Clamp target GC heap from 528MB to 512MB
>
> Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 0(0B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 512MB/512MB, paused 753us total 74.922ms
>
> WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 456.940ms for cause Alloc

It seems that when you load `Bitmap` to memory, the bitmap consume a lot of memory and as a result, there is an OOM exception.

You could refer to this: [Load Large Bitmaps Efficiently](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/resources/general/load_large_bitmaps_efficiently/) or use some third-party library which implements this feature quite well like [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) or [Glide](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Glide.Xamarin/).